# "undefined is not a function" using Fine Uploader Angular integration example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fine-uploader

I'm attempting to run the sample AngularJS integration app supplied at:

https://github.com/FineUploader/integration-examples

After plugging in the appropriate fine uploader links in index.html I receive this error on running the app:

TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at angular.module.directive.link (htp://localhost:5000/client.js:113:32)
    at nodeLinkFn (htp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:4406:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (htp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:4015:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (htp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:4018:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (htp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:4018:13)
    at publicLinkFn (htp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:3920:30)
    at htp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:983:27
    at Object.$get.Scope.$eval (htp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:8057:28)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (htp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:8137:23)
    at htp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:981:15

Line 113 of client.js is:

```
                $(element).fineUploader({
                    debug: true,
                    request: {
                        endpoint: endpoint,
                        params: {
                            sendThumbnailUrl: !qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews
                        }
                    },
```

It seems like "fineUploader" is not defined.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message and the location of the error, you are either not including jQuery on your page, or you are not including Fine Uploader (the jQuery wrapped version) on your page, or one of the two is not available by the time the directive is linked. You'll want to be sure both of these dependencies are available.

While Fine Uploader does NOT require jQuery, the example you are referring to does depend on it. I'll probably re-write the example in the near future to shed the dependence on jQuery and utilize a more current version of Angular.

Comment: I see.  The index.html does have jQuery included.  Where do I get the jQuery wrapped version of Fine Uploader?  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but the index.html does reference Fine Uploader.  Actually I filled in the "todo" lines with a reference to fine-uploader.js and fine-uploader.css.  So I believe I am including the two dependencies, jQuery and fine-uploader.  Am I missing something else?  I haven't modified anything else.  Here is the js reference I changed:  <script src="fine-uploader.js"></script>

Comment: Did you download Fine Uploader? It isn't included in the example repository.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded Fine Uploader and placed fine-uploader.js/css in the example site I'm attempting to run from github.

Comment: There's clearly something amiss with your code. You'll need to take a closer look at the dev tools console in your browser of choice.

Comment: I literally copied over file-upload.js and file-upload.css from the downloaded Fine Uploader package and put in the same directory as index.html.  I then modified index.html to reference those two files as described.  Do I need other files referenced?  Is there a dependency on the version of angular, bootstrap, or jQuery?  Perhaps there is an incompatibility with the latest Fine Uploader I downloaded?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have the correct build of fine uploader, based on the file name you provided. You'll need the jquery version, as mentioned above.

Comment: You are correct.  I didn't have the jQuery version of Fine Uploader.  Thanks!